# C++:How to make #define work with custom classes?

Tags: c++

Is there a way to make #define work with custom objects?
Here is an example to show what I mean:

```
#include <iostream>
#define i Complex z; z.Re=0; z.Im=1 //<-error
using namespace std;

class Complex{
    public:
        double Re;
        double Im;
        void operator=(Complex z){
            this->Im=z.Im;this->Im=z.Re;
        }
};

int main(){
    Complex a = i; //<- the "i" (line 15)
    cout<< a.Re<< endl<< a.Im;
    return 0;
}
```

In this code it shows an error at line 2:" expected primary-expression before 'a' ".

I want the "i" in line 15 to be replaced by an object with correct properties.

If it's not possible to make something similar work with #define, could you make that work with a completly different approach?

Comment: You want to initialize the object? Are you familiar with constructors?

Comment: Presumably this is an assignment and your job is to implement `Complex` otherwise you'd just use [`std::complex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex)?

Comment: Ditch the macro idea entirely. Have a look at *user defined literals* assuming `std::complex` is not an option, for some reason.

Comment: @AuSeR Welcome to StackOverflow. Constructing `Complex a` with a define is ... very unusual (do not do it!). You should write a constructor for the Complex class and use that so you will be able to construct `a` with something like `Complex a(0.0, 1.0);`.

Comment: What do you expect `Complex a = Complex z;` (which results from the macro expansion) to do?

Comment: [https://ideone.com/JHnxDl](https://ideone.com/JHnxDl)

Comment: `#define i ...` is evil, or rather it is evComplex z; z.Re=0; z.Im=1l ;)

Comment: No, @largest_prime_is_463035818, not in that sense.  Macro replacement works on whole (preprocessor) tokens.  It will not replace just the 'i' in "evil".

Comment: @JohnBollinger it was a joke. sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to solve this is by adding a constructor, then creating a `const` you can reference as necessary:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Complex {
public:
    double Re;
    double Im;

    // Add a simple constructor
    Complex(const double r, const double i) : Re(r), Im(i) { };

    Complex& operator=(Complex z) {
        // Don't jam things up on the same line
        this->Im = z.Im;
        this->Im = z.Re;

        return *this;
    }
};

// Define a constant. Note not `i` which is a very common iterator variable.
const Complex I = { 0, 1 };

int main() {
    Complex a = I; // Assignment is fine

    std::cout << a.Re << std::endl << a.Im;

    return 0;
}
```

Another approach would be to have `Complex::I` defined as a `static` property to avoid polluting the global namespace.

In C++ `#define` is rarely the best option. It is usually the worst. Making a `#define` well-behaved under a variety of non-trivial use-cases can be extremely challenging which is why they're best reserved for exceptional situations where every other option has been exhausted.

Comment: Also might be worth noting that `=` should not return `void`.

Comment: @Bathsheba clang doesn't give me any grief, but you're right.

Comment: it can return whatever afaik, it will only lead to surprises when chaining

Comment: It would be simpler if you omit the assignment operator override. It is not needed for this class since the default would work. Besides, the OP is just trying to construct the object `a` which can be done (better) without the assignment operator as `Complex a(0, 1);`

Comment: @nielsen It can be useful to have a constant like `I` around so you can do things like `x = y * I`.

Comment: @tadman You are probably right. You should initialize it with `const Complex I(0, 1);` though, and you still do not need to override the assignment operator.

Comment: @nielsen Sure, or you could add an [`i` modifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/operator%22%22i) to numerical constants like `std::complex` does. Or just use `std::complex`.